# Java's short spans from -32768 (=0x8000) but why do we have to cast 0x8000 to short explicitly?

Tags: java

Based on the following information,

[image]

[image]

we know that Java's `short` spans  from `-32768 (=0x8000)` to `32767 (=0x7FFF)` and casting is optional. What I don't understand is that why do we have to cast `0x8000` to `short` *explicitly*?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{        
    short x;
    x = (short) 0x8000;
    // x = 0x8000; // have to cast 0x8000 to short
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

I am using NetBeans on Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`0x8000` is firstly interpreted as an integer with the value `32768`, and then Java attempts to convert that to a short, which it is then unable to do, because `32768` doesn't fit into a short.

Note that just using `32768` instead also gives the same result:

```
short x = (short)32768;
System.out.println(x); // -32768
```

As another example, consider this line of code:

```
short x = 0xffff8000;
System.out.println(x); // -32768
```

No cast is necessary here because `0xffff8000` is the integer `-32768`, and that fits into a short.

But don't ask me why they made the decision to make things work this way (it might've been just to keep things simple for the compiler).

---

The only applicable extract I could find in the JLS comes from [5.2. Assignment Contexts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2): ([3.10.1. Integer Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1) is also relevant) (but I could certainly have missed a relevant part)

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type byte, short, char, or int:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable

Although this does, in my opinion, leave some ambiguity about the intended behaviour here.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add the sign: the positive value `0x8000` is too large for a `short`, `-0x8000` should work.

Comment: This doesn't work with any other negative short though (i.e. anything greater than 0x8000). Also, the hex representation of -32768 **is** 0x8000 (not -0x8000), as can be seen with `System.out.printf("%x",(short)-32768);`, so why is the minus symbol necessary?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "doesn't work with any other negative short". I have tested it with `-0x7FFF` and it works fine. Regarding your other point, the Java compiler will assume any integer literal is an `int`. (That's why we have to write `long` literals as `xL`.) So when interpreting `0x8000` as an `int`, it is a positive number.

Comment: By "any other negative short" I mean "anything greater than 0x8000", as in neither 0x8001 nor -0x8001 fits into a short (despite there existing a short with a hex value of 0x8001). `(short)-0x7FFF` is 0x8001 in hex. The typical use case for using a hex literal is to set a variable to that exact hex value, which this wouldn't do for any negative value other than -32768, so I'm not sure how helpful the minus symbol would be here.